# javascript class.method1.method2

Tags: javascript

i'm looking for something like :

```
document.getElementById("id").innerText.toString().length;
```

so : `class.method1().method2().method3();`

my code :

```
class Example
{
    method1(){ .. }
    method2(){ .. }
    method3(){ .. }
}
```

from out class :

```
var element = new Example();

element.method1(); //works fine
element.method1().method2(); // error: method2 is not defined
```

any solution?

thanks for all :)

Comment: That's because you're calling `.method2` on `element.method1()` (=the return value of `method1`) and not `element` itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a *fluent interface*. To implement this, just add `return this;` to the end of every method in the class.

Side note: `document.getElementById("id").innerText.toString().length;` is not a fluent interface - each function/attr returns a different value.

Comment: but how i can make something like this : document.getElementById("id").innerText.toString().length;